# How to define the real projective space $RP^1$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know there are 2 ways to define the $RP^2$: (1) identify each pair of antipode of $S^2$. (2) identify each pair of antipode on the boundary of $D^2$.

So how shall I define the $RP^1$?

If I follow the (1), then I identify each pair of antipode of $S^1$.

But if I follow (2), then I identify each pair of antipode on the boundary of $D^1$. And since $D^1$ is a segment and its boundary is 2 points. So the result is just $S^1$.

So it seems that I get two different results from (1) and (2). What is the problem?? (Maybe (1) is also $S^1$?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) is also $S^1$.  Think about the upper hemisphere only: each point gets identified with a unique point in the southern hemisphere.  Hence, we need only deal with the southern hemisphere (homeo to $D^1$, by the way).  But the endpoints $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ also get identified, so this glues together the ends of an interval to make $S^1$.  Hence (1) and (2) both give $S^1$, so $\mathbb{R}P^1$ is $S^1$.

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot !

Comment: Different way to see it is that $S^1 \to S^1, z \mapsto z^2$ induces a homeomorphism $S^1/{\sim} \to S^1$